# How to access data in a thread from another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, api, rest

I am new to threads in Java and my question is this. If we have an object inside a running thread, and that object's instance variables are being changed inside that thread. Now, if another API call is made, that wants to check the values of the changed instance variables of the Object that was in the previous thread, how can I get that data from that thread into the current thread that I'm in currently? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Such object can not be created in one of the threads. You said you are using REST API. So you have some controller or service or some other class that handles your requests. In that service (or some other class that is accessible from your service you need to have some class as a property with some state that could be updated and read. So, this object scope survives any thread and any request. So, when your request comes you can access your state object and update it or read the current state. But you have to understand that now several threads can access your state object at the same time and situation can happen when one thread tries to read the state just as another one updates it, so you can get all kinds of unpredictable behavior. So, you have to make your state object thread-safe - a term that means that your state object is aware and supports working with several threads at the same time. How to make some class thread-safe is huge topic on its own and there are different solutions to that issue. So read up on "thread-safe"

Comment: Thank you Michael for your answer.I could make the object thread safe, by my final goal is to be able to read that object's instance variables values as they are periodically being changed by one thread that my object (that implements Runnable interface) is in. But when the other rest request comes, I cannot access the new value of the instance variables inside that object because I don't have the reference of that Object (because this is a new request) but the thread is still running in the runtime (and changing the values periodically), so I want the values that are being changed.

Comment: @shivi you didn't understand my answer. Your object that implements Runnable should receive in its constructor another object that exists before and after your request. In your handling of your request you update that object. Other threads can access that object but not your Runnable.

Comment: The problem is that I can have multiple requests that want to start the process as I described earlier : to create an object( from my Class) and start changing their instance variables values, e. g. there are 3 requests that want to do this, so this means there are 3 threads and they have 3 objects in them. Now, what if I want to know the value of the instance variables of only one of the objects that is in one of the threads?

Comment: And this is why I don't understand why would having a object that exists before and after my request would help, because if that object's values would be changed by all of the 3 threads, then there would be no right result for me to read right? Sorry if I am misunderstanding something again. Thank you in advance

Comment: Your external object can have a map that would have separate entries for any of your threads

Comment: Can u provide an example of this type of map ?

Comment: @shivi this is out of scope of a question in stackoverflow.